# Heroku развёртывание приложение с дополнительными файлами

Tags: golang, heroku, развертывание

Разворачиваю приложение(Golang) на сервисе heroku
Приложению для работы нужны локальные файлы, но не нашел как явно залить эти файлы

Прошу поделится опытом, если такое возможно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заливаете вместе с кодом в репозитории через git.

Если вы спрашиваете про то, как их изменять и сохранять на сервере, то ответ - никак. Вот ссылка для ознакомления: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: Я имел ввиду следующее
1. Приложение запускается 
2. Приложение лезет в somename.conf за параметрами
Вот меня интересует можно ли залить вместе с исходниками и такой _.conf заливать

Comment: @MortimerNineStems а вы попробуйте

Comment: Спасибо. Я внимательнее прочитал мануал heroku и нашел способ, как заливать docker-контейнер, до вашей подсказки в упор видел